# Installing PostGresQL & MySQL in Mac OS X running MAMP?

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, installation, mamp

Well, I have MAMP installed on my Mac OS X, and I've got PostGres up and running, but am wondering how I can use it with PHP?  I'm assuming that there's something I need to do where I compile PHP so that it can use both, but, I'm not sure how to do that if PHP has already been installed?  Or, if there's something unique I need to do to get it work on the Mac in a MAMP environment?  I'm really unfamiliar with installations ,etc., so, help / direction / links, etc., is greatly appreciated.  I've been googling, but think maybe I'm not even searching for the right terms...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should use a PHP script containing

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

This will show you which PHP extensions are installed / enabled.

With a bit of luck, you'll have `mysql`/`mysqli`/`pdo_mysql` and `pgsql`/`pdo_pgsql` already installed -- which means it'll be OK from the PHP side : you'll just have to use the right functions/classes to connect to your pg and/or MySQL servers.

Answer (score 0):

You need the php postgres driver, you can try macports to install the php5-pgsql extension