# setup PostgreSQL with Laravel in MAMP

Tags: php, postgresql, laravel, mamp

I am using MAMP on my MAC. As it comes with MySQL by default. But now I need to use PostgreSQL in one of my project. How can I setup postgreSQL in MAMP for Laravel project?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing PostGresQL & MySQL in Mac OS X running MAMP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029566/installing-postgresql-mysql-in-mac-os-x-running-mamp)

Answer (score 12):

Ok if you are set on using postgreSQL over mySQL that comes with MAMP you have to manually install postgreSQL on you location machine the OSX packages can be found [here](http://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/),

If you don't want to do a full install i recommend this [Postgres App](http://postgresapp.com/) just download an extract to your applications folder then when you launch it the port number will be displayed in the menu bar like so:

[image: Postgres.app]

create a database:

1. go to menu above Click on Open psql
2. In the command line create you database like so: `CREATE DATABASE your_database_name;`
3. should return `CREATE DATABASE`

Tip to exit postgreSQL CLI use `\q` then  ENTER

You now need to plug these settings into Laravels configuration:

1. open file: %laravel_directory%/app/config/database.php
2. in the array replace `'default' => 'mysql',` with `'default' => 'pgsql',`
3. now with the information from before edit the `'connections'` array like so:

   ```
   'connections' => array(
       'pgsql' => array(
           'driver'   => 'pgsql',
           'host'     => 'localhost',
           'database' => 'your_database_name',
           'username' => '',
           'password' => '',
           'charset'  => 'utf8',
           'prefix'   => '',
           'schema'   => 'public',
       ),
   )
   ```
4. save file

You should now have a functioning database that Laravel can talk to.

Note you do not need the username or password in database config if you are using the [Postgres App](http://postgresapp.com/).

Comment: Could elaborate this `You should not have a functioning database that Laravel can talk to`? What do you mean by this sentence?

Comment: LIkely meant to type "now" instead of "not". Common typo - I can't edit because I need at least 6 character difference to edit other people's responses :D